# What is an alternative to Shimano FC-5700 52B Chainring?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, crankset, chainring, australia

The tooth of my outer chainring broke off so I need a replacement for it.

Problem is, it's an old crankset FC 5700 and I can't find anywhere that sells the same chainring. I don't want to replace my entire crankset and deraileurs as that would be too expensive.

What chainring would I be able to replace it with?

Could I use an 11 speed chainring/53 teeth?

The new r7000 have a different pin configuration to the 5700.

Comment: All excellent answers but none addresses the AB problem. _Why_ did teeth break off? In MTB when your bike flies over your head while your are tumbling among the rocks this is kind of obvious. But road bike dropping teeth? There has to be some underlying cause and that needs to be fixed first.

Answer (score 5):

You may have more luck searching for the chainring with the official part number. There is also a 53T version for the FC-5700 and both the 52T and 53T come in silver and black. Here are the part numbers:

**FC-5700**

- 52T (silver): Y1M398130
- 52T (black):  Y1M398140
- 53T (silver): Y1M398150
- 53T (black):  Y1M398160

According to Shimano's doc, the FC-6700 chainring is compatible with the FC-5700:

**FC-6700**

- 52T (silver): Y1LJ98090
- 52T (glossy grey): Y1LJ98150
- 53T (silver): Y1LJ98100
- 53T (glossy grey): Y1LJ98160

Then again, according to Shimano's doc, the FC-7900 chainring is compatible with the FC-6700, so *should* be compatible with the FC-5700:

**FC-7900**

- 52T-B: Y-1KY98010
- 53T-B: Y-1KY98030 (beware, 53T-A also exists)

Now these are the Shimano officially proposed replacements. The other two cranksets are also old, but you have now more options you can search for.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You should also be able to use a full FC-4700 Tiagra 10-speed crankset.

You might even find that a full FC-4700 crankset is less expensive than just a FC-5700-compatible chainring, as those are all out of production for a while now and getting rare.

And there's a good chance an 11-speed crankset would work just fine, too, but that is a bit more risky as those are optimized for a slightly-narrower 11-speed chain.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you can use any standard 130mm BCD chainring, including those made by third parties. I assume your crankset has a 130mm BCD because you referenced a 52t big ring, and cranks in those days had 130mm BCD for 53/39 or 52/39 gearing, or 110mm for compact 50/34 gearing.

Starting in 2009, the Dura Ace and Ultegra groups kept a 5-arm arrangement, but they shifted to hollow outer rings that were a fair bit stiffer than predecessors. This improved front shifting, but it was expensive, and they chose not to use those rings on the 105 5700 group. I think the Ultegra and DA cranks of that era would also take standard 130mm chainrings, they would just be visually mismatched. This is consistent with Ollie's post. Anyway, starting the *next* generation (9000, 6800, and 5800), Shimano went to a 4-arm, asymmetric 110mm BCD. SRAM also elected to go a different direction with the groups after that era of Shimano, and Campagnolo had always been slightly different (e.g. 135mm BCD, 110mm BCD but one hole was set at 112mm just because).

In any case, you certainly cannot use an 11s Shimano chainring on your crank. Shimano doesn't have any of those in 130mm BCD, and the arrangement of the crankarms is different. I haven't checked, but there could be third party 130mm BCD 11s chainrings, but that is an older BCD and these chainrings might be scarce.

There are a lot of aftermarket chainrings for the standard BCDs. They likely won't shift as well as Shimano, because they don't have access to Shimano's patents for its pins and ramps. The difference might be small, however. I don't have a comprehensive list of aftermarket manufacturers. I know that Origin8, Dimension, and possibly Surly are low-end manufacturers. Sugino and possibly FSA might be considered mid-range. Specialities TA are probably high-end, but they are a small French company that can be hard to get in the US, if you are here, and their chainrings may be nearly as expensive as stock Shimano chainrings. The latter is definitely true of their aftermarket replacements for Shimano 11s chainrings, and they also aren't hollow and thus should be not as stiff.